# Customizing PowerShell Commands Logs in Separate File

Tags: powershell

I am recording powershell commands of every process via registry.

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription
> → EnableTranscripting = 1

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription
> → EnableInvocationHeader = 1

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription
> → OutputDirectory = "" (Enter path. Empty = default)

The output of this registry is as follows:[image]

It creates a new file for every powershell process. These file includes Process ID  along with other details. Is there is anyway to add the process ID along with the txt file name.??

Like *PowerShell_transcript.ADMIN-PC.Dc3e2zQo.20201001075256-**ProcessID***
So that it is easily differentiable within multiple powershell processes log files.

Comment: If you need custom logging, then you need to do that. Enabling Transcript is an on or off thing, You cannot customize it. Also, it is not recording individual process, it's recording all that happens in a PowerShell session. Of course, a PowerShell session can spawn many processes, but they are happening in the session. If you want more tracking, then you need to enable all the PowerShell Auditing features. See the docs online for how to do that. With auditing and transcripting, then you can use those for coorelation.

Comment: @postanote thanks for your reply. Actually what i have seen is each powershell process log in singular file. The process ID is present in the file. If the process get terminated or killed. The session get terminated too. But if the porcess remains there and execute commands after specfic interval or time it will log in similar file.

Comment: PS does not have a process handle unless a PS is running.  It is that PS startup that generates a new log, not what you do in it. What you do it it gets logged. If you fire a script manually, you have to start PS. if you fire it from a TS, you have to start PS. if you shell out to PS from a PS, you now have multiple. If you run PS and do multiple commands, scripts in the session, then it all gets logged that session log. If you kill a code run and not PS, that is logged. Each new PS startup is a new single session no matter what you do in it or for how long. Close PS, the log is done.